# Let be $T$ be an additive functor and $L_i T$ its i-th left derived functor. Why $L_0 T = T$, if T is right exact?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

This is stated on the following wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_functor 
So, after this, $L_i$ is the i-th homology of the chain:
$\ldots \rightarrow TP_1 \rightarrow TP_0 \rightarrow  0 $, where $P_i$ come from a projective resolution $ \ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow M $. I do not see how $T$ being right exact helps me now, because if $ \ldots \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow 0$ is exact, then right-exactness / exactness at $TP_0$ gives me that the 0-th homology is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $P_1\rightarrow P_0\rightarrow 0$ is **not** exact. The map $P_1\rightarrow P_0$ is not surjective and its cokernel is $M$. This is because $P_\bullet$ is a projective resolution of $M$ and in particular $P_1\rightarrow P_0\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$ is exact.

Now apply $T$ to this last sequence. Because $T$ is right exact, the sequence $TP_1\rightarrow TP_0\rightarrow TM\rightarrow 0$ is exact. This mean in particular that the cokernel of the map $TP_1\rightarrow TP_0$ is isomorphic to $TM$. Thus the $0$-th homology of $TP_1\rightarrow TP_0\rightarrow 0$ is isomorphic to $TM$ as claimed in the wikipedia article.

Comment: I'm not that good with the the intuition of the cokernel. How do I see that $TM$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of $TP_1 \to TP_0$?

Comment: This is a general fact : if $A\overset{f}\rightarrow B\overset{g}\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, $C$ is the cokernel of $f:A\rightarrow B$. Indeed, the cokernel of $f$ is $B/Im(f)=B/\ker g\simeq Im(g)=M$ (here the isomorphism $B/\ker g\simeq Im(g)$ comes from the first isomorphism theorem for modules, and is part of the definition of an abelian category).